# getting desired sub string from string

Tags: php, regex

How do I get substring from string which start with `s`  and end with `/s`.

`$text` can be in following formats

```
 $text = "LowsABC/s";
 $text = "sABC/sLow";
 $text = "ABC";
```

how can I get `ABC`, sometime it may happen that `$text` does not contain `s` and `/s` just only `ABC`, Still I want to get the `ABC`.

Comment: Get everything between s and /s BUT if they are both missing get everything? do they only appear once?

Comment: what about ABCsONLYONETAG? or JUST/sENDTAG?

Comment: @Waygood: Either both tags will be present or both will be absent. No other case

Comment: just needed clarifying because the straight preg_match answer would cover none, one or both. So its not correct for what you want. You need the pre-checking of @some-non-descript-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
s(.*)/s
```

Or when you want to get a string of minimal length:

```
s(.*?)/s
```

And apply this res you can using `preg_match`:

```
preg_match( '@s(.*)/s@', $text, $match );
var_dump( $match );
```

And now you must check, if something was found or not, and if not, 
then the result must be set to the entire string:

```
if (not $match) {
   $match = $text;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$ cat 1.php 
<?
$text = "LowsABC/s";
preg_match( '@s(.*)/s@', $text, $match );
var_dump( $match );
?>

$ php 1.php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "sABC/s"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
}
```

Comment: And if they dont contain s and /s?

Comment: Getting Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: after using your updated code now I get this  preg_match(): Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3

Comment: @Waygood: you must check, if nothing was found, then use the entire string. That is better than make something like `s?(.*?)(?:/s)?`

Comment: Warning is removed now but the final output still contain `s` and `/s` can you help on this please

Comment: `$match[1]` contains `s` and `\s`? can you please show the string that you give to `preg_match`?

Answer (score 1):

Might be trivial, but what about just using something like this (Regexs aren't always worth the trouble ;) ):

```
$text = (strpos($text,'s') !== false and strpos($text,'/s') !== false) ? preg_replace('/^.*s(.+)\/s.*$/','$1',$text) : $text;
```

Comment: +1 as this covers the fact that none or both TAGS need to be present.